# Could we get a table for the editor?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

I have seen lots of posts(including some of mine) that would benefit from a table-like component in the editor. This way we could display columnar data, examples, expected results, arrays, etc... It would make for a nice clean view of what we are looking at. Does this sound like something we could add to the editor? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Sorry I did not find that. I will try it sometime! Thanks